# DOM background-Image add

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner.

I encounter a small problem which is I cannot add an image to my div block.

here is my HTML code

```
<span class = 'memepic'>
<img src ="https://encryptedtbn0.gstatic.com/imagesq=tbn:ANd9GcTmvCGIVavqB6jVObiS1sqkvwlzYgpjCVfWBg&usqp=CAU">
</span>
```

and I wrote my js code is like this one

```
//it is my <span> id
const img = document.getElementsByClassName('memepic') 

//it is my divblock id
const memebox = document.querySelector('#meme')


for(i of img){
    i.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        console.log(e)
        memebox.style.backgroundImage = 'url("e.path[0].currentSrc")';

      });
}
```

the error shows my console is

```
e.path[0].currentSrc:1 GET file:///C:/Users/kevin/Desktop/bootcamp/officialclass/meme%20generator/e.path[0].currentSrc net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

my purpose is when I click that picture, that picture will show on my divblock which is in the center of the screen.

I checked the path[0].currentSrc is correct.
and it will show the picture if I replace 'e.path[0].currentSrc' to the content inside the 'e.path[0].currentSrc'.

like this

```
memebox.style.backgroundImage = 'url("https://encryptedtbn0.gstatic.com/imagesq=tbn:ANd9GcTmvCGIVavqB6jVObiS1sqkvwlzYgpjCVfWBg&usqp=CAU");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey can you try this code in for loop :

```
`url(${e.srcElement.currentSrc})`
```

Comment: It works! thank you. but I dont understand why I cannot just url(e.srcElement.currentSrc)?

Comment: you can use template literal when some need to write js code in string expression. you can look this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Word of warning, the reason I didn't use this is because it's not supported by Internet Explorer. That's only a small percentage of users, but for maximum compatibility string concatenation guarantees cross-browser support. https://caniuse.com/template-literals

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't parse variables that are inside a string, so you're asking for the background URL to literally be set as "e.path[0].currentSrc".

Instead of this:

```
memebox.style.backgroundImage = 'url("e.path[0].currentSrc")';
```

Do this:

```
memebox.style.backgroundImage = 'url("' + e.path[0].currentSrc + '")';
```

Comment: Thank you! but I have a tiny problem still bothering me. if "" treated as string. why I can directly code this  'url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYDPc08aoHTD4C--BGJ5-gYz1xta3HOTcd6g&usqp=CAU")' . and still show the picture?

Comment: That's because the URL *is* a string, so it's fine. When you insert the variable either as above, or as in bizimsiti's answer, it's translated into a string that's inserted into url().